# Date comparison issue

Tags: java, date

I am comparing dates by this code

```
 if(new Date().after(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").
     parse(rs.getString("FromDate")))){
     permMediaRs.setTimeFrame(true);
 }
```

But it is not giving me accurate result.  So I tried to print both of them to check whether date is coming right or wrong.So when I printed them

```
    System.out.println("Today: " + new Date() + " From: "+new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(rs.getString("FromDate"));
```

Then it gave me this output.

```
   TOday: Fri May 24 12:34:38 PKT 2013  From: Thu Nov 03 00:00:00 PKT 35
```

Now you can see that `today date` is coming fine but in `From date` I am unable to understand what is `35`. I am expecting a year here but it is printing just 35. Any suggestions?

**Note:**  `rs.getString("FromDate"));` value is coming from DB and its value is `2013-05-22 00:00:00.0`

Comment: variables are your friends

Comment: Your dateformat doesnt seem to fit the date string youre trying to parse.

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings in your database? Why not store them as dates, and using ResultSet.getDate() to get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SimpleDateFormat pattern is not valid for the string "2013-05-22 00:00:00.0"

Try this one
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 2):

The format specified is `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"`,while in the DB you say you have `2013-05-22 00:00:00.0`. The parsing fail of course. It should be `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

Answer (score 1):

You dateformat is just wrong. You are using `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` but in your database is `2013-05-22 00:00:00.0` stored.

Try `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S` instead. And by the way: you should better use a `Date` field in your database than a `String`.

See the Javadoc of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).